# Find the absolute value of the difference between the area of these triangles.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Let $\triangle ABC$ and $\triangle ABC'$ be two non congruent triangles with side $AB=4$, $AC=AC'=2$$\sqrt{2}$ and $\displaystyle\angle B=30^\circ$. Find the absolute value of the difference between the area of these triangles.

Diagram:-
http://prntscr.com/1vl225

Comment: by $\angle B$ you mean $\angle ABC,$ or $\angle ABC'?$

Comment: both will be same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

Apply $$\cos 30^\circ=\frac{a^2+4^2-(2\sqrt2)^2}{2\cdot a\cdot 4}$$ where the values of $a$ represent $BC,BC'$

The area of $\triangle ABC=\frac12BC\cdot AB\cdot\sin30^\circ$ and similarly for $\triangle ABC'$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let $D$ be the midpoint of $CC'$. Then $AD \perp BC'$ and hence $AD=AB\sin \angle B$.